# How to generate a copyable link to clipboard that is clickable in gmail

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I have to generate a url to the clipboard when user click the button.
The question is, I have no idea how can I make this url clickable when I paste it into email. The result turns out to plain text.
And I am using ReactJs as my frontend framework. I have tried using Clipboard.writeText(), but it not works. I also tried to paste html code to email, but all I get is plain text.
I have seen other website implemented this function, but I really don't know how to do this.

Comment: usually you can't run code in email. you can send them to a link pointing to a page where you can run code...

Answer (score 0):

You can copy a string to the clipboard by triggering the following:

```
navigator.clipboard.writeText('text');
```

Complete example

```
const [text, setText] = useState("");

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setText(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleCopy = () => {
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(text);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" value={text} onChange={handleChange} />
      <button onClick={handleCopy}>Copy</button>
    </div>
  );
```

If that doesn't work, I'd check the console for any other errors.

[More in docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard/writeText)

Comment: Actuallly I need a clickable link in gmail. I have tried this way, it will leave plain text in gmail after I paste the content in clickboard.
However, I need feature click link button on gmail to add the clickable link for that copied text.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have solved this by myself. Just put html code as [text/html] type into clipboard api and it can be copied as it looks like in a webpage.